# How to set factor levels order according to appearance of values in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

Given a data frame like the following:

```
label digit timediff
1         9        0        
1         9        9        
1         9       17        
2         9       17        
2         9        8        
1         9        8        
2         4      200        
1         4       17        
2         4       17        
2         4        8
```

I am trying to work with consecutive digits (it's a PIN code analysis).
My PIN is 9460.

I want to analyse the timediff according to label and digit.
Firstly I have created a column using

```
df$combined_factor <- with(df, interaction(label, digit))
```

But now I need the factor levels to be according to the digit appearance.

Please advise how can I "tell" `combined_factor` column levels to be in the order of the digit appearance (9 then 4 then 6 and 0)?

I have explored the question:
[Order factor levels according to the order in which the levels appear in the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545847/order-factor-levels-according-to-the-order-in-which-the-levels-appear-in-the-dat)

But in my situation I have label in.

For example `combined_factor` can be:
1.9
2.4
...

I want it to be in the digit order: 1.9, ... 1.4, ... 1.6 ... 1.0, ... 2.9, ... 2.4, ... 2.6, ... 2.0 ....

```
label_digit    timediff
   <fct>          <dbl>
 1 1.9                0
 2 1.9                9
 3 1.9               17
 4 1.9               17
 5 1.9                8
 6 1.9                8
 7 1.4              200
 8 1.4               17
 9 1.4               17
10 1.4                8

levels(df$label_digit)
[1] "1.0" "2.0" "1.4" "2.4" "1.6" "2.6" "1.9" "2.9"
```

Expected:

```
levels(df$label_digit):
[1] "1.9" "1.4" "1.6" "1.0" "2.9" "2.4" "2.6" "2.0"
```

Comment: please can you edit your sample data according your expected output. There is no `c(6, 0)`. In addition there are three `1.9`'s. How should they ordered? Like this? 1.9,.1.9,1.9,1.4,....

Comment: In the middle of it @Jimbou

Comment: @Jimbou Have a look on my edit. The order of label_digit is ok BUT not the levels of this column. I want the order of the levels should be like the order of the digit's appearance. It should be always 9 --> 4  ---> 6 ---> 0. Additional label should be just a prefix. First will go 1.9 as much as 9 appears with label 1, then 1.4 as much as 4 appears in label 1 etc.

Comment: you might look into the `forcats` project which has some utility functions to accomplish just this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you provided poor reproducible data I will use my own:

```
d <- structure(list(label = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), digit = c(9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), timediff = c(0L, 
9L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 8L, 200L, 17L, 17L, 8L)), .Names = c("label", 
"digit", "timediff"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Then you can try a `tidyverse`

```
d %>% 
  mutate(digit=factor(digit, levels = c(9,4,6,0))) %>% 
  arrange(label, digit) 
   label digit timediff
1      1     9        0
2      1     9        9
3      1     4       17
4      1     6       17
5      1     0        8
6      2     9       17
7      2     9        8
8      2     4      200
9      2     4       17
10     2     4        8
```

Then for the interaction use:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(digit=factor(digit, levels = c(9,4,6,0))) %>% 
  arrange(label, digit) %>% 
  unite(ID, label, digit, sep=".") %>% 
  mutate(ID=factor(ID, levels = unique(ID))) %>% 
  with(.,levels(ID))
[1] "1.9" "1.4" "1.6" "1.0" "2.9" "2.4"
```

Or in base `R` simply use `order`

```
d[order(d$label, factor(d$digit,levels = c(9,4,6,0))),]
   label digit timediff
1      1     9        0
2      1     9        9
8      1     4       17
3      1     6       17
6      1     0        8
4      2     9       17
5      2     9        8
7      2     4      200
9      2     4       17
10     2     4        8
```

Then

```
d1 <- d[order(d$label, factor(d$digit,levels = c(9,4,6,0))),]
d1$combined_factor <- with(d1, interaction(label, digit))
d1$combined_factor <- factor(d1$combined_factor, levels = unique(d1$combined_factor))
levels(d1$combined_factor)
[1] "1.9" "1.4" "1.6" "1.0" "2.9" "2.4"
```

As ya function you can try

```
foo <- function(df, Code) df[order(df$label, factor(df$digit, levels = Code)),]
foo(d, c(9,4,6,0))
```

There is no need to work with the `interaction` part. If you need it. creat the interaction afterwards using 1) `tidyr`'s `unite` or 2) `interaction`. See also `?sort`: `"The sort order for factors is the order of their levels"`. Thus you simply have to change the factor levels.

Comment: This is not what I wanted, I wanted to combine label and digit and make this process automative (tomorrow I will get 1234 PIN and 3454 ....)
That's why I need a general solution to order combined_factor label+digit according to digit appearance.

Comment: > See also ?sort: "The sort order for factors is the order of their levels". Thus you simply have to change the factor levels.
This is exactly my problem - sorting the label+digit by digit order of appearance. There is a huge impact to the order of the appearance.

Comment: @steves that you have other pins is not mentiond in your question. Added a function and the correct levels...over and out

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help!
I have learnt a new smart way to do this thanks to you!